# Is it possible to subscribe to the Firebase onDisconnect() event from more than one location in the database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In an application where clients are connected to a **Firebase Realtime Database**, is it possible and/or bad practice to have more than one subscription to the `onDisconnect()` event in order to update more than one location in my database?

So for example, in addition to the following:

```
firebase.database().ref(`users/${uid}`).onDisconnect().update({
  state: 'offline'
})
```

I'd like to also update additional data elsewhere like so:

```
firebase.database().ref(`rooms/${uid}`).onDisconnect().update({
  available: false
});
```

I have tested this and it does work, but there is nothing in the Firebase documentation regarding multiple subscriptions in this way.

I also realize that I could use a Firebase Cloud Function to achieve the same thing, but is the above an acceptable approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's acceptable.  It's not clear to me what your concerns are, but if it works the way you expect, run with it.  The documentation doesn't suggest what you're doing is bad in any way.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, i proposed the question since there was nothing in Firebase's documentation regarding multiple subscriptions like this. Id rather avoid using yet another cloud function if possible, and this seems to work just fine.

Comment: Related question: can you have multiple ondisconnects queued at the same location or does one replace the other.  For example would `ref('users/${uid}').onDisconnect().remove() && ref('users/${uid}').onDisconnect().update({  state: 'offline'})` just do the update when the connection drops?